# Angular 6 / Clarity UI - Form Page Validation, upload data

Tags: angular, validation, vmware-clarity

I've set up the Clarity UI Seed project and have an issue with the Wizard form page validation when uploading data: 
Each `<form>` tag on each page get's a variable (e.g. `#formPageOne="ngForm"` `#formPageTwo="ngForm"` etc.). 
I want the Next button on the first page to be deactivated until the page is valid (formPageOne.valid = true). That works fine when you enter the data manually, but when there's invalid data on a subsequent page (after uploading and parsing a file), "formPageOne" is only valid when you fix those errors as well. 
Very strange! Any ideas?

(Needless to say that you can't fix them if you can't leave the first page!)

Comment: Please post a minimal reproduction on StackBlitz or at least some more code here, it's almost impossible to help you out here with the little information you posted. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more info on minimal reproductions.

Comment: I appreciate your comment Eudes, but I'm a bit in a tight spot: Reproducing the issue on StackBlitz would require almost as much time as reinventing the wheel. Because I would have to rewrite everything just to prove a point, since for confidentiality reasons, I cannot share the actual code.
This question therefore is intended for someone that has seen this issue before.

Comment: The point of a minimal reproduction is for you not to rewrite everything. Based on what you described, you need only 2 pages in the wizard, and a dummy input that's always invalid on the second page. Trying to write a minimal reproduction also often lets you find the solution by yourself, or identify a bug.